# uiautomatorviewer - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: android, uiautomatorviewer

I am trying to run `uiautomatorviewer` in terminal. I am getting this error:

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/<Username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/<Username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I think this might be related to the java version I am using. Here is the output of `java -version`:

```
java version "10" 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)
```

I have already seen [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47029810/uiautomatorviewer-could-not-create-java-virtual-machine), but it recommends downgrading to java 8.

Am I missing anything here? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: same issue here, going crazy :D

Answer (score 31):

`uiautomatorviewer` works fine with Java version 8. You need not downgrade java version to 1.8. Instead add this method to `.bash_profile`

```
uiautomator() {
        export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
        export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk
        export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
        /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer
}
```

This would set the JAVA_HOME path to 1.8 and includes android platform and build tools to path variable.

Either,

1. Restart your terminal to get the changes reflected or
2. Compile your `.bash_profile` by `. .bash_profile` in the current terminal to get it reflected.

Start typing `uiautomator` in your terminal. It should work !

Comment: great solution! i had multiple java versions installed and this worked for me

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :)

Comment: How do you edit .bash_profile and where is this file located on windows?

Comment: @Adamantus : I just searched for it after you have asked and came across this clip (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQSkji4WJPc) please try it out..

Answer (score 14):

> Djava.ext.dirs=/Users//Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users//Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Following worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04, Java 11):

```sh
$ export YOUR_SDK_PATH="/home/user/Android/Sdk/"

$ java -Xmx1600M -Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir="$YOUR_SDK_PATH/tools" -cp "$YOUR_SDK_PATH/tools/lib/x86_64/swt.jar":"$YOUR_SDK_PATH/tools/lib/*" com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer
```

Comment: ```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer
```
I get this error

Answer (score 8):

uiautomatorviewer is not compatible with java10 as far as I can tell. Switching to java8 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on uiautomator.bat file and click on edit.(should open up note pad with code in it)

Scroll and find "rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path."

Make sure the next 2 lines of code I have below should be the same ie make the changes so its the same.

set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe

rem call ..\lib\find_java.bat
Save file and
it will work

Answer (score 5):

use Layout Inspector instead.  its better.

[image]

Comment: this is awesome. way faster

Answer (score 5):

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04;Download java8 Compressed Archive from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) ,uncompress it to somewhere,
then open uiautomatorviewer with some text editor like gedit,and replace

```
javaCmd="java"
```

to

```
javaCmd="<you uncompressed java8 dir location>/bin/java"
```

Then it may work.

Answer (score 2):

Moving back Java 8 has fixed the problem for me. After you have installed Java 8, make sure your environment variables are not pointing to your previously installed Java.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and i did the following in my uiautomatorviewer file.
Instead of this line:

```
exec "${javaCmd}" $javaOpts -Djava.ext.dirs="$frameworkdir" -Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir="$progdir" -jar "$jarpath" "$@"
```

I replaced the same using Classpath and it worked:

```
exec java -Xmx1600M -XstartOnFirstThread -Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=/your-sdk-path/tools -cp /your-sdk-path/tools/lib/x86_64/swt.jar:/your-sdk-path/lib/uiautomatorviewer.jar:/your-sdk-path/tools/lib/*.jar:. com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer
```

Replace your-sdk-path with the location of sdk on your system. You can try this command directly on your terminal also and it will launch 'UiAutomatorViewer' without doing any changes around java.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and I tried all the solutions the people suggested, but it did not work. The only solution I found is below:

1. Install/downgrade your Java version to 8. In my case, I had Java version 17 the latest.
2. Update JAVA_HOME value in the environment variable with (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311).
3. RUN command Prompt(cmd) as administrator
4. Write (uiautomatorviewer)
5. Hit the ENTER. Check below image to show you before [image]& after applied the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on Linux, but not my friend's Mac.

In ./Android/Sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer

I replaced

```
exec "${javaCmd}" $javaOpts -Djava.ext.dirs="$frameworkdir" \
  -Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir="$progdir" -jar "$jarpath" "$@"
```

with

```
exec "${javaCmd}" $javaOpts \
  -Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir="$progdir" \
  -cp $swtpath/swt.jar:$frameworkdir/* com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer "$@"
```

using the /* CLASSPATH wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

this was a real adventure....

1. specifically get JDK version 8 (not JRE or another version)
   https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html
2. add JDK8 to your environemnt path as `JAVA_HOME`..for example:
   [image]
3. make sure `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin` is also added to your `Path` as well so that you can run `uiautomatorviewer` from any directory
   [image]
4. in terminal, run `uiautomatorviewer`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on my MacOS. Here is what I did to solve the problem.

The main issue: You need to run `uiautomatorviewer` with `Java 8`

**Step 1:** Find and locate all installed versions of Java in your MacOS

```
mdfind -name 'java' | grep '/bin/java$'
```

if you don't have Java 8, you can install it (zip) in a separate folder.

**Step 2:** Open `uiautomatorviewer` with your favorite text editor. I am using SublimeText

```
subl ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer
```

**Step 3:** Change the following line

```
javaCmd="java" // or any variation
```

to

```
javaCmd="PATH_TO_BIN_JAVA"
# for example /Users/macbook/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_322/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

No you can run the `uiautomatorviewer` without problems.