# Uiautomatorviewer not started with java 13.0

Tags: java, android, environment-variables, appium, uiautomatorviewer

I have an issue with launching uiautomaterviewer with the error:

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=mypath\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Version JAVA:13.0.2
```

thank you for help

Comment: try changing Djava.ext.dirs with -classpath

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uiautomatorviewer - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506036/uiautomatorviewer-error-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine)

Comment: @CrapoWolf thank you for your response , I tried to change it in the uiautomatorviwer.bat but I have another error "unrecognized option"