# UIAutomatorViewer startup errors out

Tags: android, adb, uiautomatorviewer

I am trying to run UiAUtomatorViewer from command prompt on Windows10 machine. But it keeps giving the following error when I run `uiautomatorviewer.bat` from the `Sdk\tools\bin` directory.

```sh
-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

[(image of above error for reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKceL.png)

`JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` environment  variables are set and I am able to use adb commands like adb devices etc well.
I also added Java install directory to the PATH variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uiautomatorviewer - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506036/uiautomatorviewer-error-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your Java version to "1.8.0_231"
you can get here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html

set the env in your bash_profile. to do that -
go to MAC DISK and find ".bash_profile"
Open,edit and put the path

example:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/x86_64
```

> quit the terminal and reopen
> type "uiautomatorviewer" and hit enter

that it.

Comment: I can try that but how is appium able to use the current version of Java to run the tests?

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt type following on Window machine

go to the bin directory

```
**cd C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>**
```

Set JAVA_HOME on command prompt by typing

```
**set JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre**
```

then run UIAutomator,

```
uiautomatorviewer.bat
```

Note : The set command does not save values between cmd.exe sessions. So JAVA_HOME is set to above temporary. So every time you need to do above steps for new cmd.exe sessions.