# Unable to open UIAutomatorviewer on Mac High Sierra

Tags: java, selenium, appium, android-uiautomator, detox

We have brand new MacBooks with High Sierra (10.13.6).
Other system info:

```
JAVA Version: java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
```

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)

JAVA_HOME: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home

When tried to open Android UIAutomatorViwer we're getting following error:

```
/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer ; exit;
```

> /Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath
>   instead. Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A
>   fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. logout Saving
>   session... ...copying shared history... ...saving history...truncating
>   history files... ...completed. Deleting expired sessions...111
>   completed.

More details:
Java is at:  /usr/bin/java

[image]

Comment: Is there an alternative for UIAutomatorviewer (apart from Appium IDE's inspector)?

Comment: Hi, Just wanted to check if anybody else faced similar issue? how did you solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Installed older java(8) JDK
- Updated Java version to 1.8 in JAVA_HOME

Commands used to update Java Version:

```
cd ~/
vim ~/.bash_profile
Updated the JAVA_HOME
Save in vim using :wq!
source ~/.bash_profile
```

[image]

- Restart & UiAutomatorViewer is working!
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You need Java 8 for uiautomator as mentioned in this as well as other threads. But you can do this without updating the JAVA_HOME variable.

Update the java_exe path in the uiautomator.bat file using any editor.

For Windows  systems, find the line

```
set java_exe=call ..\lib\find_java.bat
```

Update that to:

```
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin\java.exe
```

In this way, you don't need to update the JAVA_HOME variable which has a higher jdk version(useful for other programs).

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to upgrade to Java 11.0 but still want to run then this may help.

`uiautomatorviewer` works fine with Java version 8. You need not downgrade java version to 1.8. Instead add this method to `.bash_profile`

```
uiautomator() {
        export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
        export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk
        export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
        /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer
}
```

This would set the JAVA_HOME path to 1.8 and includes android platform and build tools to path variable.

Either,

1. Restart your terminal to get the changes reflected or
2. Compile your `.bash_profile` by `. .bash_profile` in the current terminal to get it reflected.

Start typing `uiautomator` in your terminal. It should work !

Answer (score -1):

Work perfectly!

step 1: cd ~/
step 2: vim ~/.bash_profile

-Add text "export ANDROID_HOME ..." to end text.