# can't find uiautomatorviewer-26.0.0-dev.jar

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am trying to start uiautomatorviewer under /.android/platform-tools/bin/ uiautomatorviewer but it gives me "can't find uiautomatorviewer-26.0.0-dev.jar I checked the path but I didn't find any issue. 
In one post I read that Monitor has taken the place but that is also not working.

You can see the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

This is when I try to open the monitor

[image]

Where am I doing a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `uiautomatorviewer` executable has been moved in [SDK Tools Revision 25.3.0 (Feb 2017) update](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017) to new location under `<android-sdk>\tools\bin`

Comment: I tried that also but not working. See below message. (MAC SYSTEM)
Mehmets-MBP:~ mehmetgul$ /Users/mehmetgul/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer ; exit;
-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/mehmetgul/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/mehmetgul/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778698/unable-to-open-uiautomatorviewer-on-mac-high-sierra

Comment: Hi T.Che, thanks for the help. I added below code to my bash_profile :          export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)". and it worked.  I am using java version 11.05